# "<CustomerOrder: admin>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to owerride for my order. But I get an error because it is "ManytoMany" field.

views.py:

```
    orderform = OrderForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    orderform = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if orderform.is_valid() and int(orderform["customer"].value()) == customer[0].id:
        test = orderform.save(commit=False)
        orderitems = OrderItem.objects.filter(customer_id=customer[0].id)
        test.orderitem.add(orderitems )
        orderform.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

models.py

```
class CustomerOrder(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
orderitem = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name="orderitem")
dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=200,
    choices=WORK_STATUS,
    default="Waiting",
)
pay_method = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=PAY_METHOD,
    default=1,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to save the record in the database and then add items to manyTomany. You can see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) an example of what is happening to you.

> What follows are examples of operations that can be performed using
> the Python API facilities.
>
> Create a few **Publications**:
>
> ```py
> >>> p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
> >>> p1.save()
> >>> p2 = Publication(title='Science News')
> >>> p2.save()
> >>> p3 = Publication(title='Science Weekly')
> >>> p3.save()
> ```
>
> Create an **Article**:
>
> ```py
> >>> a1 = Article(headline='Django lets you build Web apps easily')
> ```
>
> You can’t associate it with a **Publication** until it’s been saved:
>
> ```py
> >>> a1.publications.add(p1)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> ValueError: "<Article: Django lets you build Web apps easily>"
> needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many
> relationship can be used.
> ```
>
> Save it!
>
> ```py
> >>> a1.save()
> ```
>
> Associate the **Article** with a **Publication**:
>
> ```py
> >>> a1.publications.add(p1)
> ```

---

Your code should look like this

```py
    orderform = OrderForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    orderform = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if orderform.is_valid() and int(orderform["customer"].value()) == customer[0].id:
        test = orderform.save(commit=False)
        orderitems = OrderItem.objects.filter(customer_id=customer[0].id)
        orderform.save()
        test.orderitem.add(orderitems )  # <- after save
        return redirect('home')
```